# Morley rank (with an unusual definition)

Tags: model-theory

For a definable set $X \subseteq \mathbb{U}^n$, let us denote $\text{RM}(X)$ the Morley Rank $\text{RM}(\varphi(\bar{x}))$, with $\varphi(\bar{x})$ the formula defining $X$. 
Show that, for $X \subseteq \mathbb{U}^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{U}^m$, we have $\text{RM}(X \times Y)= \text{RM}(X) + \text{RM}(Y)$.

I know this should be some kind of standard result. My problem is we defined $\text{RM}$ just in case of theory $T$ strongly minimal as follows: for a type $p(\bar{x}) \in S(A)$, let $RM(p)$ be $\dim(\bar{a}/A)$ for any realization $\bar{a}$ of $p(\bar{x})$. So I suppose I have to use this definition in order to show the result above.

Comment: So are you assuming $\text{Th}(\mathbb{U})$ is strongly minimal? If not, you'll need a more general definition of Morley rank... Also, do you know how to define the rank of a formula (given the definition of the rank of a type)?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming it to be strongly minimal. The $RM$ definition I have for formulas is as follows: $RM(\varphi(\bar{x}))= \max \{ dim (\bar{a}/A): \mathbb{U} \models \varphi (\bar{a}) \}$, where $A \subseteq \mathbb{U}$ is a small set and $\varphi(x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ is a formula over $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you've defined the Morley rank of a formula in a strongly minimal theory as follows:

$\text{RM}(\varphi(\overline{x})) = \text{max}\{\text{dim}(\overline{a}/A)\mid \mathbb{U}\models\varphi(\overline{a})\}$, where $A\subseteq \mathbb{U}$ is a small set and $\varphi(\overline{x})$ is a formula over $A$.

Of course, a formula $\varphi(\overline{x})$ can be over $A$ for many choices of $A$ (i.e. any $A$ containing the parameters of $\varphi$), so to make sure the definition is well-defined, you have to check that it doesn't depend on $A$.

I'll use this fact, as well as the following dimension formula:
$$\dim(\overline{a}\overline{b}/A) = \dim(\overline{a}/A) + \dim(\overline{b}/A\overline{a}).$$

If $X$ is defined by $\varphi(\overline{x})$ and $Y$ is defined by $\psi(\overline{y})$, then $X\times Y$ is defined by $\varphi(\overline{x})\land \psi(\overline{y})$. Let $\overline{a}\overline{b}$ of maximal dimension over $A$ realize $\varphi(\overline{x})\land \psi(\overline{y})$. Then, $$\text{RM}(X\times Y)  = \dim(\overline{a}\overline{b}/A) = \dim(\overline{a}/A) + \dim(\overline{b}/A\overline{a}) \leq \dim(\overline{a}/A) + \dim(\overline{b}/A) \leq \text{RM}(X) + \text{RM}(Y).$$

In the other direction, let $\overline{a}$ of maximal dimension over $A$ realize $\varphi(\overline{x})$, and thinking of $\psi(\overline{y})$ as being over $A\overline{a}$ now, let $\overline{b}$ of maximal dimension over $A\overline{a}$ realize $\psi(\overline{y})$. Then, $$\text{RM}(X)+\text{RM}(Y) = \dim(\overline{a}/A) + \dim(\overline{b}/A\overline{a}) = \dim(\overline{a}\overline{b}) \leq \text{RM}(X\times Y).$$

**Edit:** A proof the dimension formula, as requested.

Let $\overline{a}'$ be a maximal subtuple of $\overline{a}$ which is independent over $A$, and let $\overline{b}'$ be an maximal independent subtuple of $\overline{b}$ which is independent over $A\overline{a}$ (equivalently, over $A\overline{a}'$). I claim that $\overline{a}'\overline{b}'$ is a maximal subtuple of $\overline{a}\overline{b}$ which is independent over $A$. Since the dimensions in question are the lengths of these subtuples, this is all we need to show.

It's easy to see that $\overline{a}'\overline{b}'$ is maximal. If it weren't, we could add some new $a$ from $\overline{a}$ (but then $\overline{a}'a$ would be independent over $A$, contradicting maximality) or some new $b$ from $\overline{b}$ (but then $\overline{b}'b$ would be independent over $A\overline{a}$, contradicting maximality).

To see that it's independent, note that if we had some $b\in \overline{b}'$ such that $b\in \text{acl}(A\overline{a}'\overline{b}'')$, where $\overline{b}''$ is $\overline{b}'$ with $b$ removed, then $\overline{b}'$ would not be independent over $A\overline{a}'$. Similarly, if we had some $a\in \overline{a}'$ such that $a\in \text{acl}(A\overline{a}''\overline{b}')$, where $\overline{a}''$ is $\overline{a}'$ with $a$ removed, then we could cut down $\overline{b}'$ to a minimal subtuple $\overline{b}''$ such that $a\in \text{acl}(A\overline{a}''\overline{b}'')$ (and $\overline{b}''$ is not empty since $\overline{a}'$ is independent over $A$), and use exchange to get some $b\in \overline{b}''$ to have $b\in \text{acl}(A\overline{a}'\overline{b}''')$, where $\overline{b}'''$ is $\overline{b}''$ with $b$ removed, contradicting independence of $\overline{b}'$ over $A\overline{a}'$.

That last step actually embedded the key step in for my answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056601/problem-with-forking/1058578#1058578). We could make the argument smoother and more symmetrical by noting that symmetry of forking in this context implies that also $\overline{a}'$ is independent over $A\overline{b}'$.

Comment: That was very usefull, thank you. Could you give a proof of the dimension formula you used?