# Dimension of vector spaces under surjection

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, vector-spaces, model-theory

**Definition.** Let $V$ be a vector space and $X\subseteq V$ be a definable subset in the language of vector spaces. $X$ is independent if for all $a\in X$, $a\notin span(A\setminus\{a\})$.

**Definition.** Let $V$ be a vector space and $Y\subseteq V$  be a definable subset (in the language of vector spaces). We say that $B$ is a basis for $Y$ if $B \subseteq Y$ is
independent and $span(A) = span(Y)$. The dimension of Y is the cardinality
of a basis for Y .

My question is this:

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $X,Y\subseteq V$ are definable subsets. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a definable surjection. Also, let $\dim(f^{-1}(y))=d$ for all $y\in Y$. Is the following statement always true? why?
$$\dim(X)= \dim(Y) + d$$

Comment: Do mean that $f$ should be a linear map?

Comment: I think you have missed some parts of the problem.  You seem to want $X,Y$ to be subspaces so that their dimensions make sense at all.  You need some condition on $f$ so that the dimension of $f^{-1}(y)$ makes sense.  Please check and edit the information into the question.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that Henry is using a model-theoretic notion of dimension that applies to all definable sets, not just subspaces. Because $f$ is a definable function, the question now makes sense. But Henry, it's always better to clarify the setting and include the relevant definitions when you ask a question - especially when there's a chance for confusion! Please edit your question to include a definition of $\dim$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I edited the question.

Comment: @Henry Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your definition of dimension, almost any definable map you try will be a counterexample.

For example, let $V$ be a $1$-dimensional vector space. Then any set $X\subseteq V$ has dimension $1$, except for $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$ (which both have dimension $0$).

Let $X = Y = V\setminus \{0\}$, and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be the identity map. Then for all $y\in Y$, $\dim(f^{-1}(y)) = \dim(\{y\}) = 1$. But $\dim(X) = 1$,  while $\dim(Y) +1 = 2$.

---

Here is an alternative (and more sensible) definition of dimension for definable sets: Let $X\subseteq V^n$ be a definable set, and let's assume $V$ is $\omega$-saturated (if not, take a suitable elementary extension, and evaluate $X$ there). An element of $X$ is an $n$-tuple $a$, and we define $\dim(a)$ to be the size of a maximal independent sub-tuple of $a$, equivalently the dimension of $\text{span}(a)$ in your sense. Then we define $\dim(X)$ to be $\max_{a\in X} \dim(a)$, the maximal dimension of an element of $X$.

This definition of dimension agrees with the Morley rank relative to the theory of infinite $K$-vector spaces, and it satisfies the additivity condition in your question.

---

In the comments, you asked some follow-up questions.

> (1) Is my definition of dimension coincide to Morley rank? (I used Definitions 6.1.5 and 6.1.8 and 6.1.10 of Marker's book).

No - as I said in my answer, *my* definition of dimension coincides with Morley rank.

There's a confusing thing about strongly minimal theories, which is that there are two reasonable meanings of "dimension", which are very different. Let $T$ be a strongly minimal theory.

1. Let $M\models T$, and let $A\subseteq M$ (not necessarily definable!). Define $\dim_1(A)$ to be the cardinality of a basis for $\text{acl}(A)$.
2. Let $X$ be a definable set, defined by $\varphi(x)$. Let $\mathbb{M}\models T$ be a monster model of $T$ (or at least $\omega$-saturated). Define $\dim_2(X)$ to be the maximal value of $\dim_1(a)$ over all tuples $a\in X(\mathbb{M})$.

The fact that $\dim_2$ coincides with Morley rank is Theorem 6.2.19, together with Lemma 6.2.16(i), in Marker.

In vector spaces, $\dim_1$ coincides with the ordinary notion of linear dimension, for closed sets. But it's unsatisfactory for definable sets, since it isn't invariant under elementary extensions. For example, let $T$ be the theory of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, and consider the formula $\phi(x): x = x$. We have $\dim_1(\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)) = 2$, but $\dim_1(\varphi(\mathbb{R}^{42})) = 42$, despite the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2\preceq \mathbb{R}^{42}$. So $\dim_1$ is really assigning a dimension to a particular subset of a particular model.

If you're familiar with field theory or algebraic geometry, it might be morehelpful to think about the theory of algebraically closed fields, where both notions of dimension are familiar mathematical notions.

1. If $A\subseteq K\models \text{ACF}_0$, then $\dim_1(A)$ is the transcendence degree of the field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(A)}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. If $X$ is a definable set (which is a Boolean combination of zero-sets of polynomials), then $\dim_2(X)$ is the Krull dimension of the Zariski closure of $X$.

> (2) Does acl(X)=span(X) in vector spaces?

Yes, in any *infinite* vector space $V$, $\text{acl}(X) = \text{span}(X)$ for all sets $X$. The inclusion $\text{span}(X)\subseteq \text{acl}(X)$ is clear, and for the other, note that if $b\notin \text{span}(X)$, then $b$ has infinitely many images under automorphisms of $V$, so it's not in $\text{acl}(X)$.

Of course, if $V$ is finite (which can only happen if the base field is finite), then $\text{acl}(X) = V$ for any $X$.

> (3) Does the additivity condition in my question hold for Morley rank in any strongly minimal structure (or we need to have extra assumptions)?

Yes, it does. Basically, this comes down to the fact that in any strongly minimal structure, for any tuples $a$ and $b$, we have $$\dim(ab) = \dim(a/b) + \dim(b).$$
Here $\dim$ is what I wrote as $\dim_1$ above. For a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1058685/7062).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have 3 questions. (1). Is my definition of dimension coincide to Morley rank? (I used Definitions 6.1.5 and 6.1.8 and 6.1.10 of Marker's book). (2). Does $acl(X)=span(X)$ in vector spaces?  (3). Does the additivity condition in my question hold for Morley rank in any strongly minimal structure (or we need to have extra assumptions)? Thanks!

Comment: @Henry I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer. Do you agree that in Marker's book the difference between dim_1 and dim_2, which you defined in your answer, is not clear? If you look at the paragraph before Theorem 6.2.19, you will see that it refers to the Definition 6.1.10 which is the notion of dim_ I guess!  As the last question, let me to ask: is dim_1 what we get from the pregeometry in strongly minimal theories?

Comment: @Henry Well, I think what Marker has written is perfectly clear, but things always look clearer when you already understand something! When Maker says "Morley rank agrees with the notion of dimension introduced in Definition 6.1.10" (which is $\dim_1$, which is the dimension coming from the pregeometry), he's referring to the notion of the Morley rank of a *tuple*, not the Morley rank of a definable set (and this is what he proves in Theorem 6.2.19, immediately after this remark).

Comment: Recall that if $\overline{a}$ is a tuple, then $\text{RM}(\overline{a}/A)$ is the minimum Morley rank of a definable set containing $\overline{a}$. And conversely, the Morley rank $\text{RM}(X)$ of a definable set is equal to the maximum Morley rank of a tuple $\overline{a}\in X$. So in a strongly minimal, theory, the pregeometry dimension, which I called $\dim_1$ in my answer, agrees with the Morley rank for *finite tuples*, and then if you move to Morley rank for *definable sets*, which I called $\dim_2$, the relation is the one I described in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I understood!  So if we consider a tuple $\bar{a}$ as a definable set $\phi(\bar{x}) = (x_1=a_1\wedge \dots \wedge x_n=a_n)$ then, $RM(\bar{a}/A)$ and $RM(\phi(\bar{x}))$ are not the same?

Comment: @Henry Correct, they are not the same! $\text{RM}(\varphi(\overline{x})) = 0$ (the Morley rank of any finite set is finite), but $\text{RM}(\overline{a})$ depends on the actual elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$. If they are linearly independent, then the Morley rank will be $n$.